Clicking on a specific button by javascript - Auto refresh Plus extensions
I use the Auto Refresh Plus extension to refresh the Google Chrome page. This extension has a function called automatic click, which looks for the button we defined for it after every page refresh, and if it finds that button, it clicks on that button. In the settings of this extension, there is a function that we can use Java code Inject the script - after the initial click I need to click on another button that appears. But I don't know how to write the js code to click on the second button.
Custom Scripts
Please help me write this code. This is the button that appears after the first click
<button _ngcontent-xwg-c7="" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Ticket</button>


Click a button programmatically - JS

it is not working

FYI, JavaScript != Java. They're two completely different and unrelated languages, they just happen to have similar names.

@user1023268 can you provide your code? also what is not working?
